# USB driver using WriteFile and ReadFile not working in WIndows

Tags: windows, usb

**Background:** I am a Linux expert and have very little experience in Windows. I am working on a windows driver for a USB device with 2 interfaces. My driver should open the second interface which is shown below and communicate with the interrupt OUT and IN endpoints.

```
Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 No Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 None
      iInterface              3 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
```

I am able to track this interface using the String descriptor of this interface. And I followed the following methods to do the communication

I open the a Write and a Read handler

```
// Get a handle for writing Output reports.
WriteHandle=CreateFile(detailData->DevicePath,
    GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
    (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,0,NULL);

//Get a handle to the device for the overlapped ReadFiles.
ReadHandle=CreateFile(detailData->DevicePath,
    GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE,(LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,NULL);
```

And I try to push data like this

```
if(WriteFile(WriteHandle,buf,n,&BytesWritten,NULL)==FALSE) printf("Error sending output report\n");
if(ReadFile(ReadHandle,bufI,n,&NumberOfBytesRead,(LPOVERLAPPED) &HIDOverlapped)==FALSE) printf("Error receiving input report\n");
```

**Question:** This is not working. The problem I see is if the data in buf array used as WriteFile function argument is all zeros I see the data transmission. I am surprised as if I initialise the buf as

```
buf[0] = 0x80;
buf[1] = 0x00;
buf[2] = 0xDB;
```

Or any other data other than zeros then there is no transmission and the error message is printed. Also note n=65 and BytesWritten=0 when the function is invoked. I have confirmed the transmission of zeros using a hardware USB sniffer.

Could anybody point me out where have i gone wrong? Is there a better method to communicate to interrupt endpoints in Windows than using file read and write?

Comment: It is up to the driver to properly implement the IRP_MJ_WRITE request that WriteFile() generates.  It doesn't.

Comment: The ReadFile call is wrong (you're not handling the case where the I/O is asynchronous) but sounds like you aren't getting that far anyway.

Comment: Is there an example which I can use as reference?